# Errors when downloading emscripten

Tags: cmake, emscripten

I want to download emscripten on ubuntu 12.04.I downloaded Cmake 3.3.0 then I download esmscripten_portable and I run these commands:

```
    # Fetch the latest registry of available tools.
./emsdk update

# Download and install the latest SDK tools.
./emsdk install latest
```

I got these error messages:

```
    -- Could NOT find OCaml (missing:  OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find OCaml (missing:  OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH) 
-- OCaml bindings disabled.
CMake Error at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:17 (message):
  Host GCC version must be at least 4.7!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:378 (include)

    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/clang/tag-e1.34.3/build_tag-e1.34.3_32/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/clang/tag-e1.34.3/build_tag-e1.34.3_32/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake invocation failed due to exception!
Working directory: /home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/clang/tag-e1.34.3/build_tag-e1.34.3_32
Command '['cmake', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python', '-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86;JSBackend', '-DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF', '-DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF', '-DCLANG_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF', '-DCLANG_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF', '/home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/clang/tag-e1.34.3/src']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Installation failed!
```

Comment: Messages `Could NOT find OCaml` and `Host GCC version must be at least 4.7!` are seemed to be selfexplanatory: you need OCaml library installed, and gcc of version at least 4.7.

Comment: What about OCaml library? Also, content of files, referred by lines "See also ..." sometimes gives key to the problem. As for gcc, check that variable CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER in ./CMakeCache.txt refers to the needed gcc.

Comment: You can pass `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8` to the cmake call. But I don't know how the CMake call is wrapped in the emsdk script.

Answer (score 0):

I installed all these libraries very well but when I run this command:./emsdk activate latest.I got this message:The Emscripten configuration file /home/slim/.emscripten has been rewritten with the following contents:

```
import os
SPIDERMONKEY_ENGINE = ''
NODE_JS = 'node'
LLVM_ROOT='/home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/clang/tag-e1.34.3/build_tag-e1.34.3_32/bin'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT='/home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/emscripten/tag-1.34.3'
EMSCRIPTEN_NATIVE_OPTIMIZER='/home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/emscripten/tag-1.34.3_32bit_optimizer/optimizer'
V8_ENGINE = ''
TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]

To conveniently access the selected set of tools from the command line, consider adding the following directories to PATH, or call 'source ./emsdk_env.sh' to do this for you.

   /home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable:/home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/clang/tag-e1.34.3/build_tag-e1.34.3_32/bin:/home/slim/Bureau/emsdk_portable/emscripten/tag-1.34.3
```

I run :

```
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

But when I run the command :

```
./emcc v
```

I got :

```
bash: ./emcc: No such file or directory
```